# How to use h5p in react?

Tags: windows, html, macos, reactjs

I want to use h5p(html5 package) in my project. Is there any module to use h5p in react? I have read about h5p plugin which is used in WordPress, Drupal but I want to use it in react.

Answer (score 5):

The existing plugins are based on PHP and available for WordPress, Drupal and moodle. At the time being, there is no module enabling you to use H5P (create or display content) in React.

Comment: what about now is it still not available for react ?

Comment: Not that I know of. The official H5P core still is based on plain JavaScript client-side and PHP server-side. There's also a node.js port of the server-side part and a desktop application built on top called Lumi (https://github.com/Lumieducation/Lumi) that uses React and Redux, but I don't think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: No I what I want is I can upload videos and I can add interactivity in it and i want to give that option in my app to those whowver uploads the video

Comment: Guess you will have a lot to do then, sorry.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean ? Like there is no alternative / h5p ?

Comment: I am not sure what I should explain. If you want native React conponents and nobody has created them so far - and not even taking the server-side parts into account - there's a lot to do.

Comment: Ohh that's a lot of stuff man
https://liqvidjs.org/docs/reference/Video
I have been trying out this but no luck